# Haskell reflection: does record have field?

Tags: haskell, generics, reflection

GHC Generics tools let you inspect constructor name, but what about field names?

Suppose I have a data type

```
data Foo
  = F {f :: Int}
  | OO {oo :: String}
  | Foo {f :: Int, oo :: String}
```

And I have the following piece of data

```
aFoo :: Foo
```

I can write something like:

```
ooMay :: Foo -> Maybe String
ooMay f@(Foo {}) = Just (oo f)
ooMay f@(OO {}) = Just (oo f)
ooMay f@(F {}) = Nothing
```

guarding the accessor `oo` by the constructors which I know it is safe to use upon.

Is there a way to write this using Generics? Does something like `fieldMay` exist?

```
ooMay :: Foo -> Maybe String
ooMay f = fieldMay "oo" f
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is doable. The field names are written into the `Rep` as arguments to the [`M1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:M1) type constructor (the [`Meta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Meta) argument). The Haddock glosses over `M1` and the example `Generic`-based class ignores the information in it, but now we'll need it.

Just so we know what we're dealing with:

```
ghci> :kind! Rep Foo
Rep Foo :: * -> *
= D1
    ('MetaData "Foo" "Ghci1" "interactive" 'False)
    (C1
       ('MetaCons "F" 'PrefixI 'True)
       (S1
          ('MetaSel
             ('Just "f") 'NoSourceUnpackedness 'NoSourceStrictness 'DecidedLazy)
          (Rec0 Int))
     :+: (C1
            ('MetaCons "OO" 'PrefixI 'True)
            (S1
               ('MetaSel
                  ('Just "oo")
                  'NoSourceUnpackedness
                  'NoSourceStrictness
                  'DecidedLazy)
               (Rec0 String))
          :+: C1
                ('MetaCons "Foo" 'PrefixI 'True)
                (S1
                   ('MetaSel
                      ('Just "f") 'NoSourceUnpackedness 'NoSourceStrictness 'DecidedLazy)
                   (Rec0 Int)
                 :*: S1
                       ('MetaSel
                          ('Just "oo")
                          'NoSourceUnpackedness
                          'NoSourceStrictness
                          'DecidedLazy)
                       (Rec0 String))))
```

So we basically just search for the `S1`s and pick the one with the correct name. For simplicity reasons, let's only look at the ones that have the right type beforehand.

```
class GFieldMay rep a where
    gFieldMay :: String -> rep p -> Maybe a
-- fields of the right type might match the name
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Selector s => GFieldMay (M1 S s (K1 i a)) a where
    gFieldMay name m@(M1 (K1 x))
      | name == selName m = Just x
      | otherwise = Nothing
-- any other fields must be pruned (no deep search)
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} GFieldMay (M1 S s f) a where
    gFieldMay _ _ = Nothing
-- drill through any other metadata
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} GFieldMay f a => GFieldMay (M1 i m f) a where
    gFieldMay name (M1 x) = gFieldMay name x
-- search both sides of products
instance (GFieldMay l a, GFieldMay r a) => GFieldMay (l :*: r) a where
    gFieldMay name (l :*: r) = gFieldMay name l <|> gFieldMay name r
-- search the given side of sums
instance (GFieldMay l a, GFieldMay r a) => GFieldMay (l :+: r) a where
    gFieldMay name (L1 x) = gFieldMay name x
    gFieldMay name (R1 x) = gFieldMay name x
```

And that's that

```
fieldMay :: (Generic a, GFieldMay (Rep a) f) => String -> a -> Maybe f
fieldMay name = gFieldMay name . from
```

Ta-da!

```
main = putStr $ unlines $
  [ show x ++ ": " ++ show (fieldMay "oo" x :: Maybe String)
  | x <- [F 42, OO "5", Foo 42 "5"]]
-- F {f = 42}: Nothing
-- OO {oo = "5"}: Just "5"
-- Foo {f = 42, oo = "5"}: Just "5"
```